# switches in ubuntu to use math3d.h

Tags: opengl

i was doing an opengl program and it so happens i had to use some functions in the math3d.h header and i copied it to the local directory and included

## inlcude "math3d.h"

but i get an error

transform.cpp:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to `m3dRotationMatrix44(float*, float, float, float, float)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

where m3dRotationMatrix44 is a function in math3d

usually i used for glut the switch  -lglut
SO for this what am i to do?
Thanks i advance

Answer (score 1):

How did you install `Math3D`?

If you want to do all locally you will also need to copy the library file to your local directory and add it to your link command, ie `-lmath3d` if the file name is libmath3d.a

If you mean math3d from the OpenGL Super Bible you can try to add the `math3d.cpp` to your project/makefile

http://andrewtolbert.com/svn/personal/OpenGLSuperBible/shared/math3d.cpp

Comment: Hey can u find out which package actually has math3d?
That wud b a big help

Comment: 1) Where did you copy it from? 2) Sometime you can see in the header file who wrote it and for what project. http://andrewtolbert.com/svn/personal/OpenGLSuperBible/shared/math3d.h

Comment: Sir i am quite new to linux so what am i supposed to do exactly?
i mean with the .ccp file?

Comment: Ya sir the same thing. i was getting it from superbible

Comment: It depends. I imagine you have a `makefile`, have you a list of source files in it? add the .ccp there...or...a bad way would be to write an #include "math3d.cpp" in one of your other .cpp file. could work but not recommended

Answer (score 0):

When gcc says "undefined reference" it means that you missed one or more libraries to link against. You need to find out what package math3d.h came from and link against the library inside that package.

Comment: Thanks you. Have to see the package that came with it